# Check PHP error within same file

Tags: php

How can I check whether an error has occurred in my PHP file while executing the same file. I need this because I can not view that file in the browser. I would like to write any error occurred in a textfile or a log file. Is it possible?

Comment: What kind of error? There is a error log for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging error in an log file.

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/path/to/php-error.log");
```

Comment: shall i write this in the same file which is executing?

Comment: it depends... if you want to log errors for an single file then write this at the top in that particular file, else put it in some file and include it in all files.

Comment: @ravijimagna: The `.log` file is a text file. It can might as well be a `.txt`.

Comment: tried with .txt file but i dont see anything in the file. Are parse errors also logged?

Comment: try this simple code `<?php
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "test.txt");
$con = mysql_connect();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `error_reporting(-1);` to report all errors.

Please see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) php.net page. I think you'll find what you need there.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has the `display_errors` and `error_reporting` settings for that. When set up correctly, Apache will log PHP errors in the error log.

Alternatively, you can set your own error handlers. This way you can handle any error you might have (except for fatal ones obviously.

Check the [`set_error_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function and others.